# Unable to boot puma-dev: "Unexpected Exit"

Tags: puma, puma-dev

`puma-dev` is unable to boot and fails with the error:

```
unexpected exit:
    bash: line 23: exec: puma: not found
```

`puma-dev` is not seeing that I have the `puma` gem installed. It appears to get thrown off by the multiple ruby versions. I have a `.ruby-version` and a `.ruby-gemset` so **I'm not sure why it is looking in the wrong ruby folder for the `puma` gem?**

Incidentally, I don't have any of the following files: `~/.powconfig` .`env` .`powrc` `.powenv`.

```
$ puma-dev
* Directory for apps: /Users/tom/.puma-dev
* Domains: test
* DNS Server port: 9253
* HTTP Server port: 9280
* HTTPS Server port: 9283
! Puma dev listening on http and https
! Booting app 'my_app' on socket /Users/tom/.puma-dev/my_app/tmp/puma-dev-5052.sock
my_app[5056]: bash: no job control in this shell
my_app[5056]: /Users/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem puma (>= 0.a) with executable puma (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
my_app[5056]:   from /Users/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
my_app[5056]:   from /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@my_app/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
my_app[5056]:   from /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
my_app[5056]:   from /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
! Killing 'my_app' (5056)
* App 'my_app' shutdown and cleaned up
! Detecting app 'my_app' dying on start


$ cat .ruby-version
ruby-2.5.3

$ cat .ruby-gemset
my_app

$ which puma
../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@my_app/bin/puma
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and am posting here to hopefully help others! In order to resolve the issue, I used an old[`.powenv` file](https://gist.github.com/mattscilipoti/25178ad883b226e995a0140914b691d8). My guess is that this somehow tells `puma-dev` to use the correct rvm gemset.